# Issue with Vault 0.9.6 installation On MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, hashicorp-vault, vault, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm trying to install the Vault 0.9.6 Version on MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) having chip Apple M1

Installation steps:

1. Download Vault 0.9.6 from the official website
2. Move vault to /usr/local/bin

**Error:** `zsh: segmentation fault  vault` on running `vault` cmd

**Adding .bash_profile configuration**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export M2_HOME=/Users/vivekcharma/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/vivekcharma/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin  
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

If I go with latest version the get following errors : please see attached image[image]

Issue with Vault 0.9.6 installation On MacBook Pro

Comment: 0.9.6 was released about three years ago, and its static links may not be compatible with your OS.

Comment: If I go with the latest version get status code 404. please see attached image

Answer (score 0):

Vault does not have M1 support until 1.8.0
https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/pull/12071

If you're having configuration issues with 1.8.0 you might open another question specific to that.